# LuaLaTeX font loader picks Regular variant from system font repertory but Bold from texmf-local

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I have on my system for some years TrueType versions of a an older release of a (free) font ([Vollkorn](http://vollkorn-typeface.com/)) in my `texmf-local`.

I have now downloaded the more recent release, which has more variants, and made the OpenType files system wide available (to be more precise they are in my `~/Library/Fonts`, on Mac OS X).

With `xelatex`, no problem with

```
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[ItalicFont={* Italic},
                        BoldFont={* Bold}, BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic}]
```

the new (OpenType) fonts are used. Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[%
%Numbers=Lining,
ItalicFont={* Italic},BoldFont={* Bold}, BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic}]

\begin{document}

1234567890

\bfseries 1234567890

\itshape 1234567890

\mdseries 1234567890

\end{document}
```

But with `lualatex`, well initially I didn't know how to use `luaotfload-tool` (it appears `mkluatexfontdb` has disappeared ? no such link in `texbin`) but anyhow today's TL update had a luatex update, and compiling the document above under `lualatex` triggered a database rebuild :

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc
luaotfload | db : Version mismatch; expected 2.600, got 2.510.
luaotfload | db : Force rebuild.(load luc: /usr/lo
```

However my document uses the new OpenType only for the Regular variant:

```
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "Vollkorn" -> "Vollkorn-Regular.otf"

luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "VollkornBold" -> "Vollkorn-Bold.ttf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "VollkornBoldItalic" -> "Vollkorn-BoldItalic.tt
f"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "VollkornItalic" -> "Vollkorn-Italic.ttf"
```

I went to explore a bit the relevant files, and in

```
file /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua
```

I see:

```
return {
 ["Vollkorn##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-Regular.otf", false },
 ["Vollkorn:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-Regular.otf", false },
 ["VollkornBold##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-Bold.ttf", false },
 ["VollkornBold:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-Bold.ttf", false },
 ["VollkornBoldItalic##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-BoldItalic.ttf", false },
 ["VollkornBoldItalic:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-BoldItalic.ttf", false },
 ["VollkornItalic##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-Italic.ttf", false },
 ["VollkornItalic:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;##655360"]={ "Vollkorn-Italic.ttf", false },
}
```

but in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz
```

I do find for example :

```
  ["base"]={
   ["local"]={},
   ["system"]={
 lines skipped
    ["Vollkorn-Bold.otf"]=1287,
    ["Vollkorn-BoldItalic.otf"]=1288,
    ["Vollkorn-Italic.otf"]=1289,
    ["Vollkorn-Medium.otf"]=1290,
    ["Vollkorn-MediumItalic.otf"]=1291,
    ["Vollkorn-Regular.otf"]=1292,
    ["Vollkorn-Semibold.otf"]=1293,
    ["Vollkorn-SemiboldItalic.otf"]=1294,
lines skipped
   ["texmf"]={
    ["Vollkorn-Bold.ttf"]=973,
    ["Vollkorn-BoldItalic.ttf"]=974,
    ["Vollkorn-Italic.ttf"]=975,
    ["Vollkorn-Regular.ttf"]=976,
```

Thus all files seem to be correctly indexed and identified. Why then is only Vollkorn Regular picked as the new OpenType fonts, but for Bold, Italic and Bold Italic the document uses the old `ttf` files ?

```
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/friedrichalthausen/vollkorn/
Vollkorn-Italic.ttf></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/friedric
halthausen/vollkorn/Vollkorn-BoldItalic.ttf></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local
/fonts/truetype/friedrichalthausen/vollkorn/Vollkorn-Bold.ttf></Users/XXXXXXXX/Librar
y/Fonts/Vollkorn-Regular.otf>
Output written on testvollkorn.pdf (1 page, 26788 bytes).
```

---

A work around was given by Ulrike Fischer in her [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282991/4686) which I am accepting.

However, may naive user gut feeling is that something incoherent happens with the font loading by `lualatex` in this case. Thus, if a latter answer addresses or refutes my hunch, I will consider validating it instead.

---

I am adding some info after extra testing I did following comments by `@phg`. I exchanged the newer `otf` files from my `$HOME/Library/Fonts/` (this is Mac OS) with the older `ttf` files in a sub repertory location in `texmf-local`. Did a `texhash` and `luaotfload-tool --update`. I henceforth observed the exact same phenomenon with

```
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[ItalicFont={* Italic},
                        BoldFont={* Bold}, BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic}]
```

as before: the upright font used in the document ends up being the one from `$HOME/Library/Fonts/`, the others are from `texmf-local`.

I briefly thought at that point that the explanation was that a font whose filename is `Vollkorn-Regular.{otf,ttf}` will be found by `luaotfload` only if in a system repertory if requested by `\setmainfont` under name `Vollkorn`. But this interpretation is plain wrong :

If I simply remove the `otf` font from the system repertory, do a `luaotfload-tool --update` and try again with :

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[%
ItalicFont={* Italic},BoldFont={* Bold}, BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic}]
```

then compilation succeeds and the log shows:

```
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/friedrichalthausen/vollkorn/
Vollkorn-Italic.ttf></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/friedric
halthausen/vollkorn/Vollkorn-BoldItalic.ttf></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local
/fonts/truetype/friedrichalthausen/vollkorn/Vollkorn-Bold.ttf></usr/local/texliv
e/2015/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/friedrichalthausen/vollkorn/Vollkorn-Regular.t
tf>
Output written on testluaotfload.pdf (1 page, 25202 bytes).
Transcript written on testluaotfload.log.
```

All files were found in `texmf-local`.

If I move back the `otf` file to its `~/Library/Fonts` system user location, it will be used. The strange thing in such situation is that this happens only for the upright shape. For Bold, Italic, and Bold Italic, the `texmf-local` located files are preferred over the font files in `~/Library/Fonts`.

Comment: It is not a good idea to have more than one version of a font available (also with xelatex). To find a font by name fontspec and lualatex has to check various variants (and various extensions) and can easily find the wrong font. You can try to force the correct extension with `\setmainfont{...}[Extension=.otf]`

Comment: As your suggestion solved my problem could you make it an answer ? but it raises an other issue which is that `Extension=.otf` triggers (or seems to trigger) loading by filenames and thus the `Bold= ...` etc must be changed accordingly (fortunately here adding an hyphen is the only needed step).

Comment: (this comment was before the previous one, but I needed to fix typos). I just tried `Extension={.otf}` but get `luaotfload | load : path lookup of "Vollkorn.otf" unsuccessful, falling back to  file:`. Then I added `UprightFont={* Regular}` but get `luaotfload | load : path lookup of "VollkornRegular.otf" unsuccessful, falling back to file:`. The filename on the system is `Vollkorn-Regular.otf`. Thus I finally tried `UprightFont={* -Regular}` and it does work, but I had to add `-` to the specs of all other variants.

Comment: You could also just specify the path to your font to ensure that it loads the font you want.

Comment: @Sverre, I wish to compile on different locations where I have similar set-ups but absolute paths will differ. Particularly I can have as here a `mac os` but must handle also a `linux` situation.

Comment: You could put the fonts in a subfolder to your tex document and point to it with `Path`. I do that whenever a document needs to be compiled on different computers.

Comment: @Sverre That would be a solution indeed. Simpler yet would simply be that I remove all traces of the old installation.. I only keep it temporarily to be able to recompile identically old documents. But this is silly because in the case at hand I think I only used `pdflatex` with fonts created via `fontinst` from the `ttf` fonts. Thus I have the old `ttf` but possibly no document using them (anyhow, in 2010-2011 I could not use `xetex` on my system).

Comment: @jfbu There is no defined lookup order for file system traversal, nor does Luaotfload prefer any of the recognized file formats: It will return the first entry found. BTW., it doesn’t matter in the case at hand since OTF and TTF are really the same format. If you wish for consistency at the file level, there is no other solution than using file names directly. You might then place those files somewhere under version control along with the rest of the document to ensure the correct version of the file is loaded independently of the machine it’s  built on.

Comment: @phg Am I correct in translating your comment into "Luaotfload looks at file luaotfload-names.lua.gz via Lua routines, and as a result the first entry found for a given font name as returned by Lua may not be the same as the first entry found when examining the (unzipped) file in a text editor" ? Because I have examined again that file, and there is absolutely no mix-up of the old ttf fonts in my texmf-local and the new otf fonts in my `~/Library/Fonts`. (in my use case the ttf fonts are from release 2.1 of the typeface, the otf fonts are 3-005, hence it does matter which one is picked).

Comment: @jfbu No that’s not the same. The ``.lua.gz`` file isn’t even read except when the bytecode version is missing. The font version is irrelevant too: Those version strings are meaningless and there is no way to request a specific version. You can check what font name resolves to which file using ``luaotfload-tool(1)``: If that doesn’t match what ends up in your document, set the variable *run.definer* to ``info_patch`` in the config file and observe which fonts Fontspec actually requests. Since you know the exact file names, the best advice is to use them directly.

Comment: @phg `luaotfload-tool` reports the same fonts as actually used by the document, i.e., `Vollkorn` give the `otf` file in my user account `Fonts` repertory  (whose filename is `Vollkorn-Regular.otf`), and `Vollkorn Italic` etc... the `ttf` files in `texmf`. Querying  `Vollkorn Regular` reports the `texmf` located file. I am starting to believe that the explanation might be that for some reason the `Vollkorn-Regular.ttf` in `texmf` will not be matched with `Vollkorn` (it is with `Vollkorn Regular`). I will test permuting the `ttf` and `otf` files and see what happens.

Comment: @phg yes permuting the fonts leads to what I expected. Again the `luaotfload` seems to serve the font from the system (user account) repertory if called with name `Vollkorn`. Others `Vollkorn Italic`, etc.., and `Vollkorn Regular` if I had asked for it are taken from  `texmf-local`. It does look as if only if `Vollkorn-Regular.{ttf,otf}` is in a system repertory can it be found under shortname `Vollkorn`. If located in a `texmf` tree, it must be required as `Vollkorn Regular` if using font names. (naturally I did `luaotfload-tool --update` after my exchange of font files  and a `texhash`).

Comment: further tests show that what I say at the end of last comment is wrong intuition. I have updated my answer to report.

Comment: @jfbu How does Fontspec request those fonts? What does ``luaotfload-tool`` report, if you pass it the exact same requests? Which fonts are returned can vary depending on what names a font advertises. Which is why if you care about a certain font file, you should *request that font by the file name*.

Comment: @phg ``luaotfload | loaders :    > spec "Vollkorn"``, ``luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "Vollkorn" -> "Vollkorn-Regular.otf"(load luc:  /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/vollkorn-regular.luc)``, ``luaotfload | loaders :    > name "\"Vollkorn\""``, ``[snip]> fontname "Vollkorn-Regular"``, ``[snip]> fullname "Vollkorn Regular"``,  and `Lookup/name: "Vollkorn" -> "Vollkorn-Regular.otf"`, to be compared with ``> spec "VollkornBold"``, ``Lookup/name: "VollkornBold" -> "Vollkorn-Bold.ttf"(load luc:[snip])``, ``> name "\"VollkornBold\""``, ``fontname "Vollkorn-Bold"``

Comment: @phg  ``~$ luaotfload-tool --find Vollkorn`` ``luaotfload | resolve : Font "Vollkorn" found!`` ``luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Fonts/Vollkorn-Regular.otf"``, ``~$ luaotfload-tool --find "Vollkorn Bold"`` ``luaotfload | resolve : Font "Vollkorn Bold" found!`` ``luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/friedrichalthausen/vollkorn/Vollkorn-Bold.ttf"``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to have more than one version of a font available (also with xelatex). To find a font by name fontspec and lualatex has to check various variants (and various extensions) and the search has to be "fuzzy" and so can easily find the wrong font.

You can try to force the correct extension with `\setmainfont{...}[Extension=.otf]` and by using file names instead of font names.

Comment: For people interested in the case at hand this meant using `\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[UprightFont={* -Regular}, ItalicFont={* -Italic}, BoldFont={* -Bold}, BoldItalicFont={* -BoldItalic}, Extension={.otf}]`.

Comment: I do suspect nevertheless some incoherency in the lualatex font loading. If a latter answer addresses this issue I might have to move the tick ...

Comment: @jfbu: It is not possible to check if there is a but in fontspec and/or luaotfload without the actual fonts. Beside this: fonts use various methods to name the existing font shapes and if fontspec/luaotfload where to picky some fonts would fail. So one has sometimes to live with side effects. I e.g. had the curious problem that a tex file was used as font: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/220.

Comment: For the record if people owning a mac pass by and are adventurous enough to check, [link](http://friedrichalthausen.de/vollkorn-2-1/)  for what I believe are the fonts I installed in `texmf-local` some years back, in particular as truetype, and [link](http://vollkorn-typeface.com/)  to the newer release, from which I extracted the opentype ones. I am not sure the actual font variant matters, but steps to reproduce are to put the v2.1 truetype fonts in texmf-local with the suitable texhash, and the v3 opentype fonts in `~/Library/fonts`.